# SSIS Conversion Error - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013

Currently I am working on two databases. Migrating information from an operational database to a datawarehouse with the well known Data Vault structure. However, it seems impossible for me to load data from the operational database to the data vault. I keep receiving to same errors over and over again.

I have checked multiple standard error creators:

- COLLATE of both Database structures is the same;
- No change in datatypes between operational and datawarehouse;
- Removed and rewritten queries and databases multiple times.

Error output is in the next code block. Could one of you help me out here?

If needed i can provide a screenshot of the Visual Studio error screen. I have tried googling and searching this particular problem everywhere, but I do not seem to get it fixed.

> Error: 0xC0202009 at Load SATT, SATT_DELIVERY_PRICE [439]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>
> Error: 0xC0202009 at Load SATT, SATT_DISTRICT [461]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>
> Error: 0xC0209029 at Load SATT, SATT_DISTRICT [461]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "SATT_DISTRICT.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "SATT_DISTRICT.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> Error: 0xC0047022 at Load SATT, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "SATT_DISTRICT" (461) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (474). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> Error: 0xC0202009 at Load SATT, SATT_EMPLOYEE [483]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>
> Error: 0xC02020C4 at Load SATT, CONSIGNMENT [2]: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
>
> Error: 0xC0209029 at Load SATT, SATT_EMPLOYEE [483]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "SATT_EMPLOYEE.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "SATT_EMPLOYEE.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> Error: 0xC0047038 at Load SATT, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on CONSIGNMENT returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> Error: 0xC0047022 at Load SATT, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "SATT_EMPLOYEE" (483) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (496). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> Error: 0xC0202009 at Load SATT, SATT_CUSTOMER [403]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>
> Error: 0xC0209029 at Load SATT, SATT_CUSTOMER [403]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "SATT_CUSTOMER.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "SATT_CUSTOMER.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> Error: 0xC0047022 at Load SATT, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "SATT_CUSTOMER" (403) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (416). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> Error: 0xC0209029 at Load SATT, SATT_DELIVERY_PRICE [439]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "SATT_DELIVERY_PRICE.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "SATT_DELIVERY_PRICE.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> Error: 0xC0047022 at Load SATT, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "SATT_DELIVERY_PRICE" (439) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (452). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: Could you show only the actual error messages?

Comment: Your error is that you are attempting insert a null value into a Primary key. Can't beleive I actually took time to parse that.

Comment: @Zane Op also has duplicated values for a key, apparently

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem. I saw the NULL value error. This however, is not my main problem. I understand that this is impossible and people who do this should be slapped in the face multiple times. I couldn't trace the creation of this error, no query typed by me was used in the process of this SSIS package, these are solely Visual Studio's 2013 own SSIS design tools, therefore I posted my question here, on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why there is no substitute for understanding teh meaning of your data and the meaning of error codes.  You are trying to put data into a column where you have no data in the row for that field. This could be a problem of database design where the first database allows nulls and the one you are inserting to does not or it could be an incorrect query that thorugh a bad join or where condition is not getting teh right tdata to pass to the other database or it could be a problem of incorrect SSIS pacakge design causing the data to not correctly populate based on what the business rules should be. We can't tell that - only someone who has expertise in your system can.

I can give you an a example I ran across recently though where this type of thing happened. A pacakage that had been running correctly for months (and for multiple clients) was suddenly not working for only one client and the error was that the PK was null. This made no sense at all since the PK was generated in one table and passed to two related staging tables in an earlier step and it was a required field in the staging tables. The problem came because one of the tables did not have a record to match the data in the other table and the data set for the table it was failing on took the key from the table withouth the matching record and not the one that had a value. In this case the SSIS package was at fault and needed to be fixed.

Another way this happens is if the data is not a PK in the orginating table and is in a field that allows nulls. In this case you need to fix the data and you should fix the SSIS package to send that sort of data to an exception table. You should have been doing that as a matter of course anyway.

It is far easier to troubleshoot exceptions when you send the failed data to an exception table. It also means you can process the other data if your business rules would  allow it. However, be careful of sending data to an exception table and never trying to fix those exceptions. If you have an exception table, someone should review it and try to make fixes for the problems at least weekly.

Or you could be pulling data from a query that needs adjustment. Suppose you had a case where all types of sales always included the customer id. Then the application was adjusted to let tehre be internal sales and in a fit of stupidity decided that internal customers did not have to have customer ids.  Now suddenly a field you always had filled in is occasionally empty. Application devs rearely consider other things sucha as datawarehousing and reporting that might be affected by their decisions and often don't notify the BI devs who wook on these things when they make changes. So looking for what might have changed in the underlying data model is always a possibility to consider. In this case perhaps the internal orders are not needed for the data warehouse or if they are perhaps an fake cuastomer id like -1 can be attached in the dataflow if the underlying model cannot be changed.

The biggest problem I see with your package however is that you apparently don't understand what the errors mean (or even how to pull them out from a mess of information) or you would have known all this already. You need to start looking at the errors you get and learning through Google what they mean. Then you need to apply that meaning to the way your particular database and SSIS package are designed.

You need to develop a far better way to troublshoot, so you need to set up your SSIS pacakages with logging and exception tables and the things you will need to be able to capture the problem when it occurs.

There is no such thing as an SSIS package that will work prefectly 100% of the time. Data models change, people start entering data differntly than they used to, one bad data entry person can mess up a working SSIS pacakge by putting in values that no one ever considered. Or worse the data can in error and continue on to the next location blindly.

Error handling and trapping of the data that is being sent through the process is something every SSIS package should have because you will need it. You can't think of designing an SSIS package with the assumption that everything will remain the same. You need to know it will fail when it should, it will reject bad data and it will recognize when unexpected data happens. You need to understand that things will change over time and an SSIS package needs to be able to throw up a smoke signal when they do.

I have packages that fail because there are two few records in the import file. I have packages that send data to the exception table when I was expecting an integer and I got text and on an on and on. Most of my packages spend far more tasks on fixing data, sending unfixable data to the exceptions and handling errors than they do on the actual movement of data. This is one reason why I never design a package without staging tables. Far better to fail before you get to the final destination than to have to rollback a bunch of production tables. If you are not doing those things, you need to start.

Comment: Thanks for the examples and for taking the time to answer my question. I will try to implement your tips and keep them in mind for future development of SSIS packages.